# Interrupt sequential concatMap calls after error happens in one of them

Tags: angular, asynchronous, rxjs

I have a view in my program with data that's hierarchical, so I need to do secuencial calls to the data base in order to fill in the appropiate data structures and show the view, if one of these calls fail I want to interrupt them.

I'm new to Angular so I researched a lot on the internet and found out that nested subscribes are a bad practice and should be avoided, so I used concatMap. Now, how do I interrupt the secuence of concatMaps after the preview one fails?

This is my code:

```
 getData() {        
        this.service.httpCall(null,
            url + '/test/getallprovinces').pipe(
            tap( (responsePro) => {
                if (responsePro.type === 'success') {
                      //fill in data structures
                } else {
                   //handle error and interrupt
                    throwError("error ");
                }}),
            concatMap(() => this.service.httpCall(null, url + '/test/getallcantons')),
            tap((responseCanton) => {
                if (responseCanton.type === 'success') {
                   //fill in data structures
                } else {   
                   //handle error  and interrupt               
                    throwError("error on cantons");
                }
            }),
            concatMap(() => this.service.httpCall(null, url + '/test/getalldistricts')),
            tap(responseDis => {
                if (responseDis.type === 'success') {
                    //fill in data structures
                } else {
                     //handle error  and interrupt
                    throwError("error on districts");
                }
            }))
            .subscribe(
                () => {},
                error => {console.log("something happened", error)}
                );
    }
```

Right now if an error happens it jumps to the next concatMap call and since there's no data it tries to fill the data structues and throws an ugly error there (pushing to an empty arra). I want to interrupt the call using trhowError

Edit: I've found the solution thanks in part to Joshua McCarthy. I was using `throwError` that returns an observable and continues execution. Instead I should've trhown a plain old JS exception inside the `tap`. Now it does interrupt the higher-order observables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add `catchError()` at the end of the pipe. There you can print to console log and return `EMPTY`. This should interrupt the observable chain the moment am error notification is emitted.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I added that but it still continues after I throw an error with throwError inside the tap function. It only interrupts when an js exception happens (push to an undefined array).

Comment: TAP operator has no meaning inside the rxjs chain. You should use a concatMap or a mapping operator for throwing an error